# DataGrid Cell Value Changed WPF - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, converters

I want the foreground color of the datagrid to be blue when the value changes. Thus, the user should understand that the value has changed and the save function should be activated.

For this purpose, I created a boolen property name CellInEdit in MainVM class. The CellInEdit property value will turn to True when the user changes the value in the cell. To achieve this, I created a ValueConverter class that will convert boolean type to color. But  it does not work.

These are XAML Codes:

```
<Window x:Class="TestAppDataGrid.View.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAppDataGrid.View"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TestAppDataGrid.ViewModel.ValueConverters"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestAppDataGrid.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainView" Height="450" Width="300">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:BoolenToGridForegroundConverter x:Key="bg"/>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding CellInEdit, Converter={StaticResource bg}}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
           AutoGenerateColumns="False"
           CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Width="30"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="80" />
                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding SurName}" Header="Surname" Width="180"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the Model Class:

```
public class Person:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    MainVM VM;
    public Person(MainVM vm)
    {
        VM=vm;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        { 
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            VM.CellInEdit = true;
        }
    }

    private string surName;

    public string SurName
    {
        get { return surName; }
        set
        {
            surName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SurName");
            VM.CellInEdit = true;
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This is the MainVM class:

```
public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public MainVM()
    {
        PopulatePersonList();
    }
    private void PopulatePersonList()
    {
        Persons= new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person(this)
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Alex",
                SurName = "Demon",
            },
            new Person(this)
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Jack",
                SurName = "Further",
            },
            new Person(this)
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Lisa",
                SurName = "Kyle",
            }
        };
    }
    private bool cellInEdit;

    public bool CellInEdit
    {
        get { return cellInEdit; }
        set
        {
            cellInEdit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CellInEdit");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This is the IValueConverter class:

```
class BoolenToGridForegroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool CellInEdit= (bool)value;
        if(CellInEdit)
            return Brushes.Blue; 
        else
            return Brushes.Black;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Edit: I edited the post for those who have similar problems.

The idea of changing color only in rows whose values changed seemed more reasonable based on to @Sinatr advice.

I moved CellInEdit property to Person class as mentioned in the comment. And it is fixed.

Comment: Your current binding expects `CellInEdit` property to be a part of row `DataContext`. Do you want text of all cells of row to become blue when one is changed? Or the whole table should become blue?

Comment: Good question. Actually, I was thinking of changing the foreground of all datagrid rows. But after you asked this question, the idea of changind foreground only the changed row seemed more logical.

Comment: Then just move `CellInEdit` property into `Person` class. Then your code should work. You may want to ensure `CellInEdit` is not initially set to `true`, e.g. by setting it to `false` for each new `Person` instance you create.

Comment: It became more elegant just by coloring the row. Thanx for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pollute your data models or view model classes with this pure view related state information. This can be considered an MVVM violation.
Instead, you should handle the highlighting completely in the view.
For example, it would be only acceptable to handle the cell editing state in the view model if the state is of any relevance for the data or data handling.

For proper encapsulation, you should consider extending `DataGrid` and implement the highlight logic in the extending type.

The following example shows how you can use clean MVVM to highlight both the edited cell and the edited row in the view if the cell value has changed.
In case you extend `DataGrid` you can simply move the following code to this new type.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<DataGrid PreparingCellForEdit="DataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit"
          CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding"
          RowEditEnding="DataGrid_RowEditEnding" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private string OldEditingCellValue { get; set; }
  private bool HasEditedCellValueChanged { get; set; }

  // Get and store the current value of the cell before editing
  // to enable the identification of a change.
  // When this handler is called, we know that the editing operation 
  // was not cancelled.
  private void DataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
  {
    this.HasEditedCellValueChanged = false;

    var cellContent = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row);
    if (e.Column is DataGridTextColumn)
    {
      var cellEditingElement = (TextBox)cellContent;
      this.OldEditingCellValue = cellEditingElement.Text;
    }
  }

  // Get the current value of the cell after editing
  // and identify a possible change.
  // At this point, the cell edit template is still loaded.
  // If we want to highlight the edited/changed cell, we have to wait 
  // until the 'DataGrid.RowEditEnding' event was raised, 
  // so that we can access the normal cell template.
  // If only row highlighting is required, then we don't need to handle that event 
  // and can highlight the row directly here.
  private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.EditAction is DataGridEditAction.Cancel)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (e.Column is DataGridTextColumn textColumn)
    {
      var cellContent = (TextBox)textColumn.GetCellContent(e.Row);
      string postEditValue = cellContent.Text;
      this.HasEditedCellValueChanged = !this.OldEditingCellValue.Equals(postEditValue, StringComparison.Ordinal);        
    }
  }

  // When the currently edited cell's value has changed 
  // then we can apply the highlighting of the edited row and cell 
  private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!this.HasEditedCellValueChanged)
    {
      return;
    }

    var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    if (dataGrid.CurrentColumn is DataGridTextColumn textColumn)
    {
      /* Apply the highlighting to row and cell individually */

      // Highlight the edited row
      e.Row.Background = Brushes.Orange;

      // Highlight the edited cell
      FrameworkElement cellContent = textColumn.GetCellContent(dataGrid.CurrentItem);
      var editedCell = (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;
      editedCell.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
  }
}
```